# opencv c++, cvSaveImage not saving when program is executed from php

Tags: php, c++, opencv

I am programming a face detection app using opencv c++(eclipse) on os X (lion).  The program loads an image file, detects the faces, and then saves each individual face into separate files.  The program works 100% as it is from a command line or in eclipse.  I then wrote a php script for file upload so someone can upload a jpg or png file then the script saves the photo with a unique file name.  Then at the end of the php script I have it execute the face detection program.

I am not sure what the difference is in running the application from a command line and having a php call the application to run.  Here is my code below.

function in c++:

```
    cvNamedWindow ("ROI", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvCvtColor( clone, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY );


    cvSetImageROI ( gray, *r);

    //// * rectangle  = cvGetImageROI ( clone );
    *r = cvGetImageROI ( gray );
    cvShowImage ("ROI", gray);

    k++;
    char *name=0;

    name=(char*) calloc(512, 1);
    sprintf(name, "/Users/jason/Sites/jason.dev/images/proc_images/Image%d.png", k);
    cvSaveImage(name, gray);
```

php script:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3306","xxxx","xxxx");
mysql_select_db("opencv_development");


$uploaddir = "images/";
$file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$stamp = date("YmdHis");
$random = rand(0, 999);
$newName = $uploaddir . $stamp . $random . $file;


if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['size']> 300000)     //Limiting image at 300K
{
exit("Your file is too large."); 
}



if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO recv_img (photo_name) VALUES ('$newName')");


shell_exec("./opencv '$newName'");

?>
```

As I said above, if I run the application from terminal then it outputs the individual face files. When it is executed from the php script, the image loads into the application, it does the face detection, but it does not save the individual face files.

Let me know if any further information is needed or if I was not clear about something.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the user that the php script is running as has permissions to write in the directory where you save the file ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so as I can use the same user account to run the opencv app from the terminal and it is able to save the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integer returned by `cvSaveImage` can help you find if there was an error.

After testing and looking at OpenCV source code, it seems that recent versions don't use `cvSetErrStatus` for file errors, but `errno` seems to be correctly set.

```
if(!cvSaveImage(name, gray)) {
    int error = cvGetErrStatus();
    const char * errorMessage = 0;
    if (error) {
        errorMessage = cvErrorStr(error);
    } else {
        error = errno;                   // needs #include <cerrno>
        errorMessage = strerror(error);  //       #include <cstring>        
    }
    std::cout << errorMessage << std::endl;  
    // with "echo shell_exec("./opencv '$newName'");" in php
}
```

If the error returned is "Permission denied", you could check if the user is actually the one you think it is with and `echo shell_exec('whoami');`.

Comment: First, thank you for the replies.  I tried as you suggested and the output on the webpage after upload was this:    The file test.jpg has been uploadedNo Error No Error No Error No Error No Error No Error No Error    There are in fact 7 faces detected in that photo and corresponds to the 7 "No Error messages"

Comment: @jmo I edited my answer. I was having the same "No Error" even after trying to write to "/".

Comment: Ah, ok.  Now I am getting a "Permission Denied" error for every face it is trying to save.  So does this mean that the permissions are not set correctly? And if so, I am not understanding how I can run it from the terminal and not from php.

Comment: ok, well I changed the permissions of that folder and now everything works as it should.  Thank you for your help.  I really appreciate it.